# Add offset while filling nan's in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

All,

I am looking for some help with the following problem. I have a way to achieve the desired result, however that requires a loop. So, here is the problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Assumptions:
#  1. The value at minimum index is never np.nan. I have a separate piece of logic that handles it


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 1)), columns=list('A'))

# Indices to null
random_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, 14))[:5]
random_indices = np.sort(random_indices)
df.loc[random_indices, 'A'] = np.nan
df1, df2 = df.copy(deep=True), df.copy(deep=True)

# Approach 1
df1 = df1.fillna(method='ffill')

# Approach 2
for i in random_indices:
    df2.loc[i, 'A'] = df2.loc[i-1, 'A'] + 0.1

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Please note that the value at index 0 is never np.nan and is handled separately. Approach 2 gives the desired result, but requires a loop. I would like to achieve the same result using Approach 1 or a similar function. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df1 = df1['A'].fillna(method='ffill') + df1.groupby(df1['A'].ffill()).cumcount()/10
```

Let's elaborate what `df1.groupby(df1['A'].ffill()).cumcount()/10` does.

Take the following dataframe as an example

```
1
NaN
2
NaN
NaN
3
```

- [pandas.DataFrame.ffill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) propagates last valid observation forward to next valid. `df1['A'].ffill()` would be

```
1
1
2
2
2
3
```

In this part, if you have some duplicate values before NaN, you can use `df1['A'].notnull().cumsum()` to replace `df1['A'].ffill()`.  `.notnull().cumsum()` classifies the NaN and previous **one** value into same group. While `.ffill()` classifies the NaN and previous adjacent equal values into same group.

- [pandas.DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) can take the Series to determine the groups. By using the result of `df1['A'].ffill()`, the 1st and 2nd rows are in the same group, the 3rd, 4th, 5th rows are in the same group.
- [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) numbers each item in each group from 0 to the length of that group - 1.

```
0
1
0
1
2
0
```

Full program

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 1)), columns=list('A'))

random_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, 14))[:5]
random_indices = np.sort(random_indices)
df.loc[random_indices, 'A'] = np.nan

df1, df2 = df.copy(deep=True), df.copy(deep=True)

df1 = df1['A'].ffill() + df1.groupby(df1['A'].ffill()).cumcount()/10
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, when I try the proposed suggestion, my entire dataframe just got filled with nan's. Could you paste a working example ? Also, can you please assume the offset is fixed ? For e.g. If I just want to add 0.1 to the previous valid value while using fillna with 'ffill', would you know how to be able to achieve that ?

Comment: @UGuntupalli Edited my answer.